# How many solutions are there to $\sum_{i=1}^3 x_i^2+x_iy_i+y_i^2=k$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, quadratic-forms

Let $k$ be a positive integer. Let
$$Q=
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 &1/2&   &   &   &   \\
1/2& 1 &   &   &   &   \\
   &   & 1 &1/2&   &   \\
   &   &1/2& 1 &   &   \\
   &   &   &   & 1 &1/2\\
   &   &   &   &1/2& 1 
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

> How many solution $x\in\mathbb Z^6$ are there to $\quad  x^tQx=k$?

This is equivalent to:

> How many solution $x\in\mathbb Z^6$ are there to 
>   $$x_1^2+x_1x_2+x_2^2+ x_3^2+x_3x_4+x_4^2+ x_5^2+x_5x_6+x_6^2=k?$$

or to

> How many solution $x\in \mathbb Z\left[\omega \right]^3$ are there to $\quad x^* I_3 x=k$?

where $I_3$ is the $3\times3$-identity matrix and $\omega=\frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}$.

I know that there is a formula for this number (there is only one class in its genus), but I don't know it.

This question is related to

- [which integers take the form x^2 + xy + y^2 ?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78361/which-integers-take-the-form-x2-xy-y2)
- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44139/how-many-solutions-are-there-to-fn-m-n2nmm2-q/

but they don't answer my question.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "formula". For example, the quadratic form $x^2+y^2+z^2$ is also alone in its genus, but there is no simple way to determine the number of representations $x^2+y^2+z^2=k$. There is a formula involving class numbers and the square part of $k$, but it only connects two subtle quantities, neither of which is simpler than the other.

Comment: @GH: True, but here the number of variables is even, so the theta function is
a modular form has integral weight and the formula for its coefficients
should be reasonably simple.


Comment: Thank Noam, I had not been able to explain it. Do you know some reference in where this formula "could be"?

Comment: @emiliocba: As usual I don't know a reference, and it would be easier
to (re)construct the formula than to locate it in the literature.
If you already know the formula it's just a matter of checking that
it gives rise to a modular form in the appropriate space and that
this space is small enough that there a unique candidate form.
If not, itshould be possible to surmise the formula from the first few
dozen coefficients of the theta function
$\left(\sum_{x,y\in\bf Z} q^{x^2+xy+y^2}\right)^3$.


Comment: @Noam: You have a point, but if we decompose spectrally (into Hecke eigenforms) we might get a contribution from cusp forms which is probably not so simple to describe. On the other hand the level is small here, so there might be no cusp forms at all.

Comment: @GH There are no cusp forms here. In any case I think if the form is unique in its genus the theta function must be in the Eisenstein subspace.

Comment: @Noam: You are absolutely right, I don't know how I missed that. I also posted a supplement to your answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The formula that emiliocba seeks seems to be as follows.
Let $\chi$ be the Dirichlet character mod $3$.  For $k>0$
write $k = 3^e n$ with $n \equiv \pm 1 \bmod 3$.  Then
the number of representations of $k$ by this quadratic form $A_2^3$ is
$$
s(k) :=
9 (3^{2e+1}-\chi(n)) \phantom. \sum_{d|n} \phantom. \chi(n/d)\phantom. d^2.
$$
I append **gp** code that verifies that this holds for $k \leq 432$.

To prove it in general it will be enough to check that
$$
\varphi := 1 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \phantom. s(k) q^k
$$
is a modular form of weight $3$ and character $\chi$ for $\Gamma_0(3)$,
and to match a few coefficients with the theta function $\theta_{A_2^3}$.
In principle, it is enough to match only the $q^0$ coefficient:
the dual of $A_2^3$ is isomorphic with the scaling of $A_2^3$ by $1/3$,
so by Poisson summation $\theta_{A_2^3}$ is modular also for
the normalizer $\Gamma_0^+(3)$ of $\Gamma_0(3)$ (generated by $\Gamma_0(3)$ and
the involution $w_3 : \tau \longleftrightarrow -1/3\tau\phantom.$);
and $\Gamma_0^+(3)$ has only one cusp,
and no cusp forms of weight less than $6$ (the weight of
$\eta(\tau)^6 \eta(3\tau)^6$), so the normalized Eisenstein series $\varphi$
is the only candidate for $\theta_{A_2^3}$.

```
H = 24
A2 = sum(m=-H,H,sum(n=-H,H,q^(m^2+m*n+n^2))) + O(q^(3*H^2/4+1));
L = A2^3;

chi3(m) = kronecker(m,3)
{
s(k, e,n) =
  e = valuation(k,3);
  n = k / 3^e;
  9 * (3^(2*e+1)-chi3(n)) * sumdiv(n, d, chi3(n/d)*d^2)
}

L == 1 + sum(k=1,3*H^2/4,s(k)*q^k)
```

Comment: Your formula works for $k\leq 10^4$. This is a great answer! Thank you for your time. 

Answer (score 7):

This is a supplement to Noam Elkies' nice answer. The coefficients $s(k)$ can be expressed as
$$ s(k)=27\sum_{d\mid k}\chi(k/d)d^2-9\sum_{d\mid k}\chi(d)d^2, $$
hence the function $\varphi$ is a linear combination of
$$E_1:=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{d\mid k}\chi(k/d)d^2q^k
\quad\text{and}\quad
E_2:=1-9\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{d\mid k}\chi(d)d^2q^k.$$
The latter functions are proportional to the standard Eisenstein series
$$ E_1':=\sum'_{m,n\in\mathbb{Z}}\chi(m)(mz+n)^{-3}
\quad\text{and}\quad
E_2':=\sum'_{m,n\in\mathbb{Z}}\chi(n)(mz+n)^{-3},$$
which form a basis of the space of modular forms $M_3(\Gamma_0(3),\chi)$, hence indeed $\varphi$ lies in this space. For more details see Section 7.1 in Miyake: Modular Forms, especially Lemma 7.1.1 and Theorem 7.1.3.

Answer (score 4):

Let's recall that the number $R(k)$ of representations of $k$ as $x^2+y^2$ can be written as follows: write $k=2^\alpha bc$ where $b$ is composed entirely of primes congruent to 1 (mod 4) and $c$ is composed entirely of primes congruent to 3 (mod 4). Then $R(k)=0$ unless $c$ is a square, in which case $R(k) = 4\tau(b)$, where $\tau(b)$ is the number of divisors of $b$.

A very similar proof would surely address the number $S(k)$ of representations of $k$ as $x^2+xy+y^2$: write $k=3^\alpha bc$ where $b$ is composed entirely of primes congruent to 1 (mod 3) and $c$ is composed entirely of primes congruent to 2 (mod 3). Then I believe that $S(k) = 0$ unless $c$ is a square, in which case $S(k) = 4\tau(b)$. (Or maybe it's $6\tau(b)$.) I guess we should also mention $S(0)=1$.

In your original question, the number of representations of $k = x^t Qx$ where $x\in{\mathbb Z}^6$ will be exactly the triple convolution $\sum_{m=0}^k \sum_{n=0}^{k-m} S(m)S(n)S(k-m-n)$. ($Q$ is positive definite so we needn't worry about negative integers.) This probably leads to a rather different-looking formula than one would get from modular forms.